# Definition of strictly convex preference

Tags: preferences, decision-theory, theory, demand

Let $x,y\in X$.

Does strictly convex preference (which implies that the utility is strictly quasiconcave) mean that:

$x\succsim y$ implies $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\succ y$ for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$?

Comment: yes, if you add the assumption that $x \ne y$.